# How to access remote Git repositories using Jenkins Freestyle Project

Tags: git, macos, jenkins, ssh, raspberry-pi

I have a Jenkins installation into my Mac, it is the `jenkins.war` inside my `/Users/myuser/jenkins folder`. Ran it the first time and Jenkins creates `/Users/mysuer/.jenkins` folder and deploy the artefacts there. Running it I'm going to `/Users/myuser/jenkins/java -jar jenkins.war`.

Additionally I created free style project that it using Git as a source code repository and is suppose to be connected each 5 minutes to and external repo that is into a raspberry pi 4.

Setup an rsa ssh key that was generated into the MacOS side and use it to connect via ssh to the raspberry and it not any problem.

Additionally setup on the Jenkins credentials as follows:

```
Scope: Global (Jenkins, nodes ... )
Id: Some id
Description: Some description
Username: My-MacOS-User
Private Key: The private key generate into my Mac side (id_rsa)
Password: The private key passoword
```

And when try to run the project always getting:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h -- ssh://pi@raspberrypi/home/pi/server/git/myRepo HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Permission denied, please try again. 
Permission denied, please try again. 
pi@raspberrypi: Permission denied (publickey,password). 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Uploaded the public and the private key into `/home/pi/.ssh`, created `.ssh` folder into the `./.jenkins` folder with the `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`
Added the `.ssh` to the `./jenkins` folder too
Created a config file

And none of them seems to work ....

Any ideas how to setup properly

Answer (score 1):

Finally I could do it !

Don't forget to use the user pi in the credentials.

And an additional problem is that the generated key wasn't registered into the ssh-agent, so Jenkins is not finding the key when try to authenticate to the Raspberry Pi.

To register the key just need to follow what is explained into [Generating a new SSH key and adding it to the ssh-agent](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@2.21/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)

Once the key is added ... voila .... everything works perfect !

Answer (score 0):

Double check on the Raspberry side that the public key (`id_rsa.pub`) was added to `~pi/.ssh/authorized_keys`

That is needed for Jenkins to connect to that Raspberry box.

You should not have to upload those keys to `/home/pi/.ssh` (especially the private key which, as its name indicates, should remain private)

---

> Additionally setup on the Jenkins credentials as follows:
>
> ```yaml
> Scope: Global (Jenkins, nodes ... )
> Id: Some id
> Description: Some description
> Username: My-MacOS-User     <<===== should be pi
> Private Key: The private key generate into my Mac side (id_rsa)
> Password: The private key passoword
> ```

Jenkins should use the SSH credential using the rmeote account "pi", not the local MacOS account.

Comment: `id_rsa.pub` from the Mac computer side is added as `~pi/.ssh/authorized_keys`, i use this one to connect via ssh to the Raspberry and it works perfectly, does not work from Jenkins side.

Comment: @JRod The username used for your Jenkins SSH credential should be pi (the remote account), not My-MacOS-User